# iOSでアプリから特定のwifiへ接続をさせるためにはプロファイルを配布することで可能でしょうか

Tags: ios

iOSアプリ初心者です。これから作成するために調査をしています。

iOSの端末に対して、アプリからwifi接続先を切り替えるという操作をしたいのですが、以前はこちらのサイトではできないということで回答があったので、念のためうかがわせてください。

構成プロファイルを作成しておいて、アプリインストール時にプロファイルをインストールさせることで、アクセスができる場所にきたら、パスワードの入力なく自動的にwifiを切り替えることは可能でしょうか？

プロファイルをインストールさせるには、いくつか方法があるようですが、アプリ側から自動的に端末に設定することはできますか？一度ユーザの許可をはさまないとできないでしょうか？

調査の段階で知識不足で申し訳ありません。ご回答いただけましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

構成プロファイルをインストールして，SSIDとパスワードの入力を省略することはできます．
Wi-Fi接続先を切り替えることはiOSのアプリケーションからはできません．

自分の知る範囲では，プロファイルのインストールにはユーザーのインストール操作が必要です．

IO-DATAのアクセスポイントの自動設定などで利用されています．
http://www.iodata.jp/product/network/info/app/qrconnect.htm

QRコードにSSID，パスワードの情報が入っていて，iOSアプリ内で構成プロファイルを作成していますが，ユーザーが「インストール」ボタンなどを押す必要があります．